# Regex to insert text BEFORE a line containing a match?

Tags: regex

I have a bunch of artists that are named in this fashion:

```
Killers, The
Treatment, The
Virginmarys, The
```

I need them to look like

```
The Killers
The Treatment
The Virginmarys
```

I'm able to match the lines with `, The` (`(^|\n)(.*, The)` is what I've used) but the more advanced syntax is eluding me. I can use `regex` on the replacement syntax as well (it's for a `TextPipe` filter so it might as well be for `Notepad++` or any other `Regex` text editor).

Comment: What do you mean by "the more advanced syntax is eluding me." Could you show it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the following:

```
Find: (\S+),\s\S*
Replace: The $1
```

Or include the `The`..

```
Find: (\S+),\s+(\S+)
Replace: $2 $1
```

Depending on your editor, you may be better off using `\1`, `\2`, and so on for capture groups.

Comment: Regex is pretty amazing but it's so hard to wrap my head around. This works great and will help clean titles from over 15gb of text! Whew

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to specifically capture the title before the comma, do so:

```
(^|\n)(.*), The
```

And replace it putting the "the" in the right place:

```
\1The \2
```

Answer (score 0):

[Regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) define *matches* but not substitutions.

How and in which way you can perform substitutions is *highly dependant on the application*.

Most editors that provide regular expression support work on a line per line basis.

Some of them will allow substitutions such as

```
s/^(.*Banana)/INSERTED LINE\n\1/
```

which would then insert the specific pattern before each match. Note that others may not allow newlines in the substitution pattern at all. In VIM, you can input newlines into the command prompt using `Ctrl+K Return Return`. YMMV.

In Java, you would just first print the insertion text, then print the matching line.